# Swift async functions with Task.sleep in it causes segmentation fault

Tags: swift, concurrency

I'm learning Swift concurrency now, and I've written some code to have a try on it. I've expected the "photo" with greater id to be "downloaded" earlier.

```swift
func downloadPhoto(id: Int) async -> String {
    print("Download started")

    let total = 3
    try! await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(total - id) * 1_000_000_000)

    print("Download ended")

    let str = "Photo \(id)"
    print(str + " downloaded")
    return str
}
Task{
    print("Program started")

    async let firstPhoto = downloadPhoto(id: 0)
    async let secondPhoto = downloadPhoto(id: 1)
    async let thirdPhoto = downloadPhoto(id: 2)

    let photos = await [firstPhoto, secondPhoto, thirdPhoto]

    print(photos)
}
```

However, when I saved the code to `test.swift` and run it with `swift test.swift`, I got the following output:

```
Program started
Download started
Download started
Download started
```

That is, none of the code after `Task.sleep` executed. To find out what's going wrong, I changed

```
try! await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(total - id) * 1_000_000_000)
```

to

```
try! await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 3)
```

and this time I got the expected output,

```
Program started
Download started
Download started
Download started
Download ended
Download ended
Photo 1 downloaded
Download ended
Photo 2 downloaded
Photo 0 downloaded
["Photo 0", "Photo 1", "Photo 2"]
```

Then, I changed the parameter `3` to `300000` and ran again. This time I got

```
Program started
Download started
Download started
Download started
Please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project and the crash backtrace.
zsh: segmentation fault  swift test.swift
```

I don't know why the first version doesn't yield a segmentation fault message, nor do I know why there is a segmentation fault. Seems that once the time to sleep grows large enough to some degree the segmentation fault occurs.

Here is the crash log:

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               swift-frontend [72033]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-frontend
Identifier:            swift-frontend
Version:               ???
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        zsh [70066]
Responsible:           Terminal [70064]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2022-02-17 00:08:58.2001 +0800
OS Version:            macOS 12.2.1 (21D62)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        7B963A0A-2299-D9C6-8085-A5F2F172ABC9

Sleep/Wake UUID:       A1819DA4-A7E6-453F-AC28-5B0CD7C84E42

Time Awake Since Boot: 330000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2804 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        1  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos.cooperative

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000108364208
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000108364208
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Region Info: 0x108364208 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 521  Bytes before following region: 581549560
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      mapped file                 108330000-108364000    [  208K] r--/r-- SM=COW  ...t_id=be3988bd
--->  GAP OF 0x22a9c000 BYTES
      MALLOC_TINY                 12ae00000-12af00000    [ 1024K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  

Thread 0::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_malloc.dylib                 0x1a7698e18 szone_free_definite_size + 240
1   swift-frontend                         0x101db5258 swift::GenericSignatureBuilder::EquivalenceClass::~EquivalenceClass() + 408
2   swift-frontend                         0x101db5258 swift::GenericSignatureBuilder::EquivalenceClass::~EquivalenceClass() + 408
3   swift-frontend                         0x101d91950 swift::GenericSignatureBuilder::Implementation::~Implementation() + 392
4   swift-frontend                         0x101bfa0c4 swift::ASTContext::Implementation::Arena::~Arena() + 716
5   swift-frontend                         0x101bdafb4 swift::ASTContext::~ASTContext() + 288
6   swift-frontend                         0x100e9fd5c swift::CompilerInstance::~CompilerInstance() + 316
7   swift-frontend                         0x100d685b4 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 2488
8   swift-frontend                         0x100cc2df8 main + 932
9   dyld                                   0x1072910f4 start + 520

Thread 1 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos.cooperative
0   ???                                    0x108364208 ???
1   libswift_Concurrency.dylib             0x2257fb7b0 swift_job_runImpl(swift::Job*, swift::ExecutorRef) + 76
2   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a76d431c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396
3   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a76d4b58 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a787d2c8 _pthread_wqthread + 228
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a787c018 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 2::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos.cooperative
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1a78463a8 access + 8
1   swift-frontend                         0x104ff2dac llvm::sys::fs::access(llvm::Twine const&, llvm::sys::fs::AccessMode) + 84
2   swift-frontend                         0x104ff6120 llvm::sys::findProgramByName(llvm::StringRef, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::StringRef>) + 416
3   swift-frontend                         0x104ff6ea8 printSymbolizedStackTrace(llvm::StringRef, void**, int, llvm::raw_ostream&) + 588
4   swift-frontend                         0x104ff79f0 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&, int) + 100
5   swift-frontend                         0x104ff6acc llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() + 128
6   swift-frontend                         0x104ff8004 SignalHandler(int) + 292
7   libsystem_platform.dylib               0x1a78984e4 _sigtramp + 56
8   libswift_Concurrency.dylib             0x2257fad6c swift::runJobInEstablishedExecutorContext(swift::Job*) + 280
9   libswift_Concurrency.dylib             0x2257fb7b0 swift_job_runImpl(swift::Job*, swift::ExecutorRef) + 76
10  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a76d431c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396
11  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a76d4b58 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a787d2c8 _pthread_wqthread + 228
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a787c018 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 3::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos.cooperative
0   ???                                    0x108364208 ???
1   libswift_Concurrency.dylib             0x2257fb7b0 swift_job_runImpl(swift::Job*, swift::ExecutorRef) + 76
2   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a76d431c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396
3   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a76d4b58 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a787d2c8 _pthread_wqthread + 228
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a787c018 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a787c010 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 1 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000108364208   x1: 0x000000010720b200   x2: 0x000000013af06e90   x3: 0x0000000000000001
    x4: 0x000000000000000e   x5: 0x0000000000000001   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x000000013b8f3c98   x9: 0x000000000000290b  x10: 0x00000000000efc50  x11: 0x0000000000179f41
   x12: 0x000000013af00000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x000000005d61b963  x15: 0x000000000000bb0a
   x16: 0x000000066f80f7b4  x17: 0x0000000108364208  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000013b8ecb90
   x20: 0x0000000000000000  x21: 0x000000013b8f4040  x22: 0x000000013b8f3c90  x23: 0x000000016f1db0e0
   x24: 0x000000013b8ecb90  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000232b23e38  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000016f1db0e0   fp: 0x000000016f1dae90   lr: 0x00000002257fad6c
    sp: 0x000000016f1dae60   pc: 0x0000000108364208 cpsr: 0x60001000
   far: 0x0000000108364208  esr: 0x82000007 (Instruction Abort) Translation fault

Binary Images:
       0x1a7694000 -        0x1a76befff libsystem_malloc.dylib (*) <961751ed-f18b-30d4-8025-aa12ca23197b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
       0x100cac000 -        0x105e23fff swift-frontend (*) <a80c4d84-e9ff-3e38-8e35-666b1f91f585> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-frontend
       0x10728c000 -        0x1072ebfff dyld (*) <d21a73ea-79cd-36eb-8ac9-2c5cf5181a27> /usr/lib/dyld
               0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? (*) <00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000> ???
       0x2257bd000 -        0x225810fff libswift_Concurrency.dylib (*) <50b9f80c-f39b-3792-b642-1ff1684a50b3> /usr/lib/swift/libswift_Concurrency.dylib
       0x1a76bf000 -        0x1a7705fff libdispatch.dylib (*) <93e1dcfc-ef56-3113-8e7c-1ba85266a93b> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
       0x1a787a000 -        0x1a7886fff libsystem_pthread.dylib (*) <f7b2eccf-e6f1-3109-ae81-9028c0b8332a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
       0x1a7844000 -        0x1a7879fff libsystem_kernel.dylib (*) <384945e6-dd71-37e5-9a3d-84fff14a1e60> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x1a7894000 -        0x1a789bfff libsystem_platform.dylib (*) <49cf1536-27e5-3a34-9724-d75552cbab56> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 40
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 2506

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=684.4M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=684.4M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=813.9M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=813.9M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
Kernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 
MALLOC                           179.2M       18 
MALLOC guard page                   96K        5 
MALLOC_MEDIUM (reserved)         240.0M        2         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
MALLOC_NANO (reserved)           384.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
STACK GUARD                       56.1M        5 
Stack                             10.1M        5 
VM_ALLOCATE                        1.0G        1 
VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)             256K        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
__AUTH                             112K       14 
__AUTH_CONST                       219K       44 
__DATA                             765K       43 
__DATA_CONST                      4898K       46 
__DATA_DIRTY                       164K       23 
__LINKEDIT                       590.7M        3 
__OBJC_CONST                        12K        6 
__OBJC_RO                         82.1M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         3104K        1 
__TEXT                            93.6M       49 
dyld private memory               1024K        1 
mapped file                       14.9M        5 
shared memory                       32K        2 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              2.6G      278 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     2.0G      278 



-----------
Full Report
-----------

{"app_name":"swift-frontend","timestamp":"2022-02-17 00:08:58.00 +0800","app_version":"","slice_uuid":"a80c4d84-e9ff-3e38-8e35-666b1f91f585","build_version":"","platform":1,"share_with_app_devs":1,"is_first_party":1,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 12.2.1 (21D62)","incident_id":"269117E0-1DFC-40A1-B7CF-5AEFE9FCF4D7","name":"swift-frontend"}
{
  "uptime" : 330000,
  "procLaunch" : "2022-02-17 00:08:58.0437 +0800",
  "procRole" : "Unspecified",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "MacBookPro17,1",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 7991622767392,
  "coalitionID" : 14494,
  "osVersion" : {
    "train" : "macOS 12.2.1",
    "build" : "21D62",
    "releaseType" : "User"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2022-02-17 00:08:58.2001 +0800",
  "incident" : "269117E0-1DFC-40A1-B7CF-5AEFE9FCF4D7",
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "pid" : 72033,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 7991626514464,
  "translated" : false,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "procName" : "swift-frontend",
  "procPath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Toolchains\/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain\/usr\/bin\/swift-frontend",
  "parentProc" : "zsh",
  "parentPid" : 70066,
  "coalitionName" : "com.apple.Terminal",
  "crashReporterKey" : "7B963A0A-2299-D9C6-8085-A5F2F172ABC9",
  "responsiblePid" : 70064,
  "responsibleProc" : "Terminal",
  "wakeTime" : 2804,
  "sleepWakeUUID" : "A1819DA4-A7E6-453F-AC28-5B0CD7C84E42",
  "sip" : "enabled",
  "vmRegionInfo" : "0x108364208 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 521  Bytes before following region: 581549560\n      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT\/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL\n      mapped file                 108330000-108364000    [  208K] r--\/r-- SM=COW  ...t_id=be3988bd\n--->  GAP OF 0x22a9c000 BYTES\n      MALLOC_TINY                 12ae00000-12af00000    [ 1024K] rw-\/rwx SM=PRV  ",
  "isCorpse" : 1,
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000108364208","rawCodes":[1,4432740872],"type":"EXC_BAD_ACCESS","signal":"SIGSEGV","subtype":"KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000108364208"},
  "vmregioninfo" : "0x108364208 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 521  Bytes before following region: 581549560\n      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT\/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL\n      mapped file                 108330000-108364000    [  208K] r--\/r-- SM=COW  ...t_id=be3988bd\n--->  GAP OF 0x22a9c000 BYTES\n      MALLOC_TINY                 12ae00000-12af00000    [ 1024K] rw-\/rwx SM=PRV  ",
  "extMods" : {"caller":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"system":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":2506,"task_for_pid":40},"targeted":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"warnings":0},
  "faultingThread" : 1,
  "threads" : [{"id":2669441,"queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":19992,"symbol":"szone_free_definite_size","symbolLocation":240,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":17863256,"symbol":"swift::GenericSignatureBuilder::EquivalenceClass::~EquivalenceClass()","symbolLocation":408,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":17863256,"symbol":"swift::GenericSignatureBuilder::EquivalenceClass::~EquivalenceClass()","symbolLocation":408,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":17717584,"symbol":"swift::GenericSignatureBuilder::Implementation::~Implementation()","symbolLocation":392,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":16048324,"symbol":"swift::ASTContext::Implementation::Arena::~Arena()","symbolLocation":716,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":15921076,"symbol":"swift::ASTContext::~ASTContext()","symbolLocation":288,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":2047324,"symbol":"swift::CompilerInstance::~CompilerInstance()","symbolLocation":316,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":771508,"symbol":"swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*)","symbolLocation":2488,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":93688,"symbol":"main","symbolLocation":932,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":20724,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":520,"imageIndex":2}]},{"triggered":true,"id":2669443,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":4432740872},{"value":4414550528},{"value":5283802768},{"value":1},{"value":14},{"value":1},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":5294210200},{"value":10507},{"value":982096},{"value":1548097},{"value":5283774464},{"value":0},{"value":1566685539},{"value":47882},{"value":27640526772},{"value":4432740872},{"value":0},{"value":5294181264},{"value":0},{"value":5294211136},{"value":5294210192},{"value":6159184096},{"value":5294181264},{"value":0},{"value":9440476728,"symbolLocation":16,"symbol":"taskHeapMetadata"},{"value":0},{"value":6159184096}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":9219059052},"cpsr":{"value":1610616832},"fp":{"value":6159183504},"sp":{"value":6159183456},"esr":{"value":2181038087,"description":"(Instruction Abort) Translation fault"},"pc":{"value":4432740872,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":4432740872}},"queue":"com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos.cooperative","frames":[{"imageOffset":4432740872,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":255920,"symbol":"swift_job_runImpl(swift::Job*, swift::ExecutorRef)","symbolLocation":76,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":86812,"symbol":"_dispatch_root_queue_drain","symbolLocation":396,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":88920,"symbol":"_dispatch_worker_thread2","symbolLocation":164,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":13000,"symbol":"_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":228,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":8216,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":2669444,"queue":"com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos.cooperative","frames":[{"imageOffset":9128,"symbol":"access","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":70544812,"symbol":"llvm::sys::fs::access(llvm::Twine const&, llvm::sys::fs::AccessMode)","symbolLocation":84,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":70557984,"symbol":"llvm::sys::findProgramByName(llvm::StringRef, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::StringRef>)","symbolLocation":416,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":70561448,"symbol":"printSymbolizedStackTrace(llvm::StringRef, void**, int, llvm::raw_ostream&)","symbolLocation":588,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":70564336,"symbol":"llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&, int)","symbolLocation":100,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":70560460,"symbol":"llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers()","symbolLocation":128,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":70565892,"symbol":"SignalHandler(int)","symbolLocation":292,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":17636,"symbol":"_sigtramp","symbolLocation":56,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":253292,"symbol":"swift::runJobInEstablishedExecutorContext(swift::Job*)","symbolLocation":280,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":255920,"symbol":"swift_job_runImpl(swift::Job*, swift::ExecutorRef)","symbolLocation":76,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":86812,"symbol":"_dispatch_root_queue_drain","symbolLocation":396,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":88920,"symbol":"_dispatch_worker_thread2","symbolLocation":164,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":13000,"symbol":"_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":228,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":8216,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":2669445,"queue":"com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos.cooperative","frames":[{"imageOffset":4432740872,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":255920,"symbol":"swift_job_runImpl(swift::Job*, swift::ExecutorRef)","symbolLocation":76,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":86812,"symbol":"_dispatch_root_queue_drain","symbolLocation":396,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":88920,"symbol":"_dispatch_worker_thread2","symbolLocation":164,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":13000,"symbol":"_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":228,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":8216,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":2669446,"frames":[{"imageOffset":8208,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":6}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7103660032,
    "size" : 176128,
    "uuid" : "961751ed-f18b-30d4-8025-aa12ca23197b",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_malloc.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_malloc.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4308254720,
    "size" : 85426176,
    "uuid" : "a80c4d84-e9ff-3e38-8e35-666b1f91f585",
    "path" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Toolchains\/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain\/usr\/bin\/swift-frontend",
    "name" : "swift-frontend"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 4415078400,
    "size" : 393216,
    "uuid" : "d21a73ea-79cd-36eb-8ac9-2c5cf5181a27",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  },
  {
    "size" : 0,
    "source" : "A",
    "base" : 0,
    "uuid" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 9218805760,
    "size" : 344064,
    "uuid" : "50b9f80c-f39b-3792-b642-1ff1684a50b3",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/swift\/libswift_Concurrency.dylib",
    "name" : "libswift_Concurrency.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7103836160,
    "size" : 290816,
    "uuid" : "93e1dcfc-ef56-3113-8e7c-1ba85266a93b",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libdispatch.dylib",
    "name" : "libdispatch.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7105650688,
    "size" : 53248,
    "uuid" : "f7b2eccf-e6f1-3109-ae81-9028c0b8332a",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_pthread.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7105429504,
    "size" : 221184,
    "uuid" : "384945e6-dd71-37e5-9a3d-84fff14a1e60",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_kernel.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7105757184,
    "size" : 32768,
    "uuid" : "49cf1536-27e5-3a34-9724-d75552cbab56",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_platform.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_platform.dylib"
  }
],
  "sharedCache" : {
  "base" : 7102480384,
  "size" : 3091218432,
  "uuid" : "296eb28e-6aeb-3129-8fa6-feb92261a4eb"
},
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=684.4M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=684.4M(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=813.9M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=813.9M(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nActivity Tracing                   256K        1 \nKernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 \nMALLOC                           179.2M       18 \nMALLOC guard page                   96K        5 \nMALLOC_MEDIUM (reserved)         240.0M        2         reserved VM address space (unallocated)\nMALLOC_NANO (reserved)           384.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)\nSTACK GUARD                       56.1M        5 \nStack                             10.1M        5 \nVM_ALLOCATE                        1.0G        1 \nVM_ALLOCATE (reserved)             256K        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)\n__AUTH                             112K       14 \n__AUTH_CONST                       219K       44 \n__DATA                             765K       43 \n__DATA_CONST                      4898K       46 \n__DATA_DIRTY                       164K       23 \n__LINKEDIT                       590.7M        3 \n__OBJC_CONST                        12K        6 \n__OBJC_RO                         82.1M        1 \n__OBJC_RW                         3104K        1 \n__TEXT                            93.6M       49 \ndyld private memory               1024K        1 \nmapped file                       14.9M        5 \nshared memory                       32K        2 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              2.6G      278 \nTOTAL, minus reserved VM space     2.0G      278 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {
    "queue" : "com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos.cooperative"
  }
},
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "60356660bbe37970735c5624",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 250000013
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "60da5e84ab0ca017dace9abf",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000008
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "607844aa04477260f58a8077",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_MORPHUN_ASSETS" : "6103050cbfe6dc472e1c982a"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000066
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "602ad4dac86151000cf27e46",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_DICTATION_ASSETS" : "61fb0e87c773c43cde3bb80e"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000305
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "5fc94383418129005b4e9ae0",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000231
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "5ffde50ce2aacd000d47a95f",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000106
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "601d9415f79519000ccd4b69",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_TEXT_TO_SPEECH" : "620161cb295c182621eced20"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000389
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [

  ]
}
}
```

I think maybe I misunderstood the way to use Task.sleep. I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me why the segment fault occurs and how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Check `Console.app` to see the crash backtrace

Comment: @JustSomeGuy Thanks for your advice. I've added it to the post